# Show that this function is a projection & describe the kernel and image of this figure

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that the function $$\mathbb{R}^{n×n}\to \mathbb{R}^{n×n}, A\to \frac{(A+A^{tr})}{2}$$ is a projection & describe the kernel and image of this figure

Observation: So we see that any vector space homomorphism $φ:V \to V$ with $φ∘φ=φ$ is a projection.

Hello! I couldn't solve this problem, is there an answer so that I can proof this question.

Comment: 1) Could you say what you have attempted ? 2) Remark : it is the projection on the subspace of symmetric matrices.

Comment: Have you tried computing $\varphi\circ\varphi$?  What happened when you tried that?

Comment: @MichaelBurr I don't know how to solve this even computing φ∘φ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I denote matrix trasponsition using $'$, so what you wrote as $A^{tr}$ I'll write as $A'$.

Just notice that $(A+A')' = A'+A''=A'+A=(A+A')$

Therefore $(\varphi \circ\varphi)(A)= \frac{\frac{A+A'}{2}+\frac{A+A'}{2}}{2}$
which is just $\frac{A+A'}{2}$, which is $\varphi(A)$. Since the choice of $A$ was arbitrary, $\varphi$ is idempotent and is therefore a projection (because it's also a linear transformation).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Do you also know how I can describe the kernel and image of this function

Comment: Yes, the kernel will be the set of antisymmetric $n\times n$ matrices, that is matrices which satisfy $A = -A'$ (notice that the diagonal entries must be 0). The image of this function will be the set of all symmetric matrices, because if $A = A'$ already then $\varphi(A) = A$ (just substitute, it's immediate), and as seen before the image of a matrix by $\varphi$ is a symmetric matrix so the image will be the set of symmetric $n \times n$ matrices.